# SymPy integration of Matrix with multivariable entries

Tags: sympy

I am using Sympy to integrate a Sympy Matrix whose components depend on variables (x,y).  Integrating with respect to a single variable `x` (or `y`) works, and returns the expected Matrix whose components are the integrals of the components of the original vector.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x,y

V = sp.Matrix(4,1,[1,x,y,x*y])
display(V)

# This works
I = sp.integrate(V,(x,0,1))
display(I)
```

Ultimately, I would like a double integral.  I can accomplish this with the following

```
Ix = sp.integrate(V,(x,0,1))
I = sp.integrate(Ix,(y,0,1))
display(I)
```

My question is why the following does not seem to work.

```
I = sp.integrate(V,(x,0,1),(y,0,1))
```

The error I get is :

```
     ValueError: Invalid limits given: (((x, 0, 1), (y, 0, 1)),)
```

Is this a bug?  Or am I using the wrong syntax for the double integral with a Matrix type?  This syntax works on components of the Matrix, i.e.

```
# This works
I3 = sp.integrate(V[3,0],(x,0,1),(y,0,1))
```

Comment: How about `integrate(integrate(V, (x,0,1)),(y,0,1))`?  This indefinite double integral makes most sense: `integrate(integrate(V, x),y)`

Comment: This is a bug. Using `V.integrate((x, 0, 1), (y, 0, 1))` works.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for confirming that this was a bug in SymPy.  This is now fixed in SymPy.  See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/23277.

The other suggestion - using

```
I = V.integrate((x,0,1),(y,0,1))
```

may even be a nicer solution.